Please fix the grammar on the first sentence of the Stack Exchange Network description popup
Currently, when you click the button towards the top left saying "Stack Exchange", a popup titled "Stack Exchange Network" appears. Below it, it says (emphasis added by me):

Stack Exchange network consists of 183 Q&A communities including Stack Overflow, the largest, most trusted online community for developers to learn, share their knowledge, and build their careers.

The grammar of the first sentence is incorrect. The word "The" should be before "Stack Exchange Network", reading like this (emphasis added by me):

The Stack Exchange network consists of 183 Q&A communities including Stack Overflow, the largest, most trusted online community for developers to learn, share their knowledge, and build their careers.

Could this please be fixed?

Not sure why others have downvoted, but often these minor issues tend to get downvoted since they're publicly seen as making a huge deal out of something relatively minor (the same form is also used to report more "severe" bugs).

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog well how am i suppossed to report it then because it is an issue...

@testing-for-ya will fix, but i think something displayed on every site should have higher standards...

Theres some that are simply about capitilization which are probably same/less importance. @testing-for-ya

@testing-for-ya yet again, no one ever said "Drop everything and place all resources to fix this". This is more a "By the way, at some point this little thing exists and should be fixed" type of thing.
